# PHP/Zend learning resources for a Ruby/Rails dev?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zend-framework

Are there any good resources for learning PHP/Zend (perhaps specifically) for a Ruby/Rails dev? Some sort of crash course would be ideal!

I just need to know the basics so I can work on a PHP app that has been built with the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the unfortunate position of having to use the ZF, they do have pretty good documentation here, though it's not on par with Rails' (it should be enough to let you work on a legacy app though): http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is very good. So is the previously mentioned [Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/reference.html) and to put it all together are a couple of good quickStart tutorials:

the first is [Rob Allen's ZF 1.x tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)
The second would be the [ZF quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

These should get you up and running...

Answer (score 1):

I found the Zend certification study guide was a good reference that covers what you're expected to know. It will give you some perspective: http://www.zceguide.com/